# In Crystal Reports I am looking to have a header footer then header footer with linked info but different Sums

Tags: crystal-reports

So I know it is not possible to do

```
header 1  
detail  
footer 1  

header 2  
detail  
footer 2
```

But I am trying to make a form that shows

```
Invoices  
Invoice#,  Date,  Status,  Total,  Balance Due  
Info  
                              Debits total:    

Credits  
Date,  Reference,  Total,  Balance  
info  
                              Credits Total:  
                              Balance due:
```

Balance due being debits - credits. I was able to get the invoices but I can not figure out how to get the Credits to show below the debits total.

Edit------------------------------------------------------------------------

Help with the below requirement aswell:

```
    sum(case when s.[ar sale bill to] like '%wilco%' 
then isnull(d.[ar saled qty requested],d.[ar saled qty]) * d.[ar saled unit price] 
else 0 end) as 'Total'
```

I need to have a value if it is `null` grab to qty from `[ar saled qty]` any ideas?

Now I am having trouble with getting it on the same page...Detail 1 prints on page one and Detail 2 Prints on page 2.  The amount of records vary but on the first record there is 3 lines in the first subreport and 1 in the second subreport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your requirement is definitely possible....

Use two sub reports in single main report where you can get desired structure

```
header 1  //sub report 1
detail    //sub report 1
footer 1  //sub report 1

header 2  //sub report 2
detail    //sub report 2
footer 2  //sub report 2
```

Let me know incase any issue

Comment: Thanks! another question for you... I am having trouble with the syntax on a formula field.... I can get it to work within SQL... here is the syntax  
sum(case when 
  s.[ar sale bill to] like '%wilco%'   
 then isnull(d.[ar saled qty requested],d.[ar saled qty]) * d.[ar saled unit price] 
 else 0 end) as 'Total' 
I need to have a value if it is null grab to qty from [ar saled qty] any ideas?

Comment: It is hard to read the formulas in comments... either you need to edit the existing question or you should post the new question... for now I am editing your question to include your new requirement...

Comment: @TonyBergeson ok now what is the problem with your formula?

Comment: That SQL statement runs fine but I am wondering how i can pull that same info in Crystal.  I use a group by clause to only get the information that i need in the SQL statement but when i import it to crystal it says not to have group by statements.  is it ok just to pull that straight from the database like that or do i need to do it within Crystal?

Comment: you can do the grouping part in crystal... you have lot of functionality available in crystal for that purpose.. you can go `Insert group` to insert a group and then you can add the summation

Comment: Thanks! That worked great! Now I am having trouble with getting it on the same page...Detail 1 prints on page one and Detail 2 Prints on page 2

Comment: it varies. in the first record there is 3 in the first and 1 in the second

Comment: have you checked the option `new page after` for detail section 1 in section expert? check that

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just separate the Debits vs Credits using a Group of Invoice Type.

That way you can just add a summary of the balance on the group footer. It should serve your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my report on separate pages.  I was looking in the section expert and all the keep together's where checked so i knew it had to be a formatting issue.  I went in and suppressed all the fields that i was not using in the subreport like report header/group header instead of just making the sections as small as they could go and that did the trick.